# JSF 2.0; MyFaces; Form submit only with POST

Tags: jsf, post, jsf-2, get, servlet-filters

i've got a security question and i don't know, how to do this in JSF.
In PHP i can react on a form submit that is defined as POST, that i only want values via POST so there is no way to get an value via GET from the same name of the field.

Example:
fieldname in form:  username
in my PHP site i can get the value via `$_POST["username"]` but not with `$_GET["username"]`, because i don't implement the GET way, only POST.

So, now i want this in my JSF site too.
The problem is, that i can't only implement POST for all requests, i must react on GET also.
I only want, that my form data will come via POST to my bean and not via GET.

How can i reach this?
With a filter or something else?
For your interest: i'm not able to use JavaScript in my application.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your question but if you just need to check if a method on your backing bean was invoked using POST or GET you can get that information from the HttpServletRequest object like so :

```
  @ManagedBean(name="myBean")
  @ViewScoped
  public class MyMBean implements Serializable{



    public void handleForm(){

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

        if(req.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){

            //Handle your form data
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a clumsy way. Generally, whenever you need to import something from `javax.servlet.*` package in a JSF backing bean, then the chance is big that there are better, more JSF-ish, ways to achieve the same, or that you actually shouldn't be using a JSF backing bean at all. You'd need to think twice then.

Answer (score 2):

Just check [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29).

```
if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()) {
    // It's a JSF POST request.
}
```